# Move constructor and char array argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

```
struct Foo
{
    char data[100];

    template<int T>
    Foo(char (&&var)[T])
    {
        data = std::move(var);
        var = 0;
    } 
};

int main()
{ 
    char v[100];
    //..init v
    Foo f( std::move(v) );   //error C2664: 'Foo::Foo<100>(char (&&)[100])' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [100]' to 'char (&&)[100]'
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get why MSVC is not happy with the line `Foo f( std::move(v) )` ? (Maybe this code is senseless)

Comment: How exactly do you *move* an array? You can move the elements of one array to another, but not the array itself.

Comment: it's just for educational purpose

Comment: I think the compiler is complaining that it cannot create an rvalue reference to an array. This is just a guess from googling "&& C++11" since I know next to nothing about C++11.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) algorithm, from the `<algorithm>` header.

```
auto it = std::move(data, data + T, var);
```

after checking that `T` isn't larger than 100. But moving `char` doesn't have many benefits over just copying.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Foo f( std::move(v) );
```

is legal for GCC, Clang and Intel. Visual Studio however complains and yields

```
error C2664: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [100]' to 'char (&&)[100]'
1>          You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

This seems a bug to me. Indeed, `v` is an lvalue but `std::move` cast it to an rvalue reference.

Since arrays of chars are not movable, although legal, I don't see much use for taking them by rvalue reference. If you really want the code to compile, a workaround is making `f` taking a regular (lvalue) reference and remove the `std::move` at the call site. Or even better, make `f` take a pointer to `char*` (`f` doesn't need to be a template). In this case, calling `f(v)` passes the address of `v[0]` (i.e. the first element of `v`) to `f`. This is the so called *array-to-pointer* conversion which is implicitly performed by the compiler.

However, as others have pointed out, the lines

```
    data = std::move(var);
    var = 0;
```

are illegal for all compilers. `data` and `var` are arrays (or references to arrays) and arrays are not assignable. For instance, the error raised by `var = 0;` by each compiler is as follows:

GCC:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [100]'
```

Clang:

```
error: array type 'char [100]' is not assignable
```

Intel:

```
error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

Visual Studio:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'char [100]'
```

Comment: Found this answer when googling the same question. I am not clear, after reading though, what does one do with the move constructor in such a class? Do we delete it altogether? Do I still implement it, but strcpy the char array inside the move constructor? You've covered an explanation, but didn't really cover what to do.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Actually, I wouldn't add this move constructor. (See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641776/move-constructor-and-char-array-argument/15646200?noredirect=1#comment22194276_15641776) in the OP.) The author said the question was for ["educational purpose"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641776/move-constructor-and-char-array-argument/15646200?noredirect=1#comment22194636_15641776) which made me interpret the question as "why the compiler is complaining?" rather than "what is a sensible implementation for such constructor?".